# Values show up in custom home page but not in custom post pages

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, templates, advanced-custom-fields

ACF values are only showing in the front page, regardless of my Location settings rules clearly stating that these values can show in "Post Type" = "Post".

[image]

I read about the `get_option('page_for_posts')` parameter but didn't work for me. Should the option string reflect the page template you are trying to read? Cause I changed it to "home" and "front-page", but didn't work either.

Someone knows what can I do to have the values show in my single post template?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any other plugins that may be altering the normal editing screen? One thing to try is to go to a post editing screen and use the "screen options" tab at the top right. Maybe the ACF box is unchecked, and checking it will make it appear? In either case the ACF fields will only appear on the back end - in the editing window - and not on the front end, the user-facing side of your site. You'll use functions like `get_option()` in your theme to display them on the front end. They can't and won't display on the front end, to visitors, without manually setting that up.

Comment: I had a few things wrong that I fixed by using Query Monitor and understanding I was pointing to an incorrect template file. But yes, I made it work with get_option() and using the correct page as parameter.